# OpenGL / GLSL viewport cut after resize

Tags: java, opengl, viewport, projection, clip

I have written a display manager for LWJGL (OpenGL in Java). Everything works very well except of the 3D rendering part.

The 3D rendering part uses a FrameBuffer and a Shader. After every resize i generate a new FrameBuffer and Textures with the new size. The Shader isnt using any resolution uniforms.

The main problem part:
When I resize my window, there is only the box of the old display size visible. The 3D object is rendered normally over the whole screen except of the box.

Keep in mind, 2D rendering, after screen quad rendring, is working well.

## Here are two screenshots:

[Normal Window](http://prntscr.com/4taz17)

[Resized Window](http://prntscr.com/4taz8u)

Would be nice to get some hints.

**Edit:** RenderBuffer size hasn`t been updated... FIXED

Answer (score 3):

You also need to set the viewport to the size of your window or framebuffer. (see [`glViewport`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glViewport.xhtml)). Initially, the viewport will be set to the size of the drawable when the context is fisrt bound to, but it will never be implicitely updated at all.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn`t change anything. Is there another way when I use an own matrix system ? I`m calculating them on my own and using GLSL 400.

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize the viewport by calling [`glViewport`](http://docs.gl/gl4/glViewport) whenever the size of the window changes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue: when I was resizing my FrameBuffer, I missed to update the **renderbuffer size**, so the renderbuffer still was 800x600 but the screen was 1300 x 900